# Extract data from API call and save file

Tags: python, json, parsing, for-loop, extract

after making post call of API I want to extract specific key/value and than save it onto a text file.

What have been done so far:-
(1)Rest api call and return list

```
import requests
import json

#API details
url = "http://192.168.1.100:9792/api/scan"
body = json.dumps({"service":"scan", "user_id":"1", "action":"read_all", "code":"0"})
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

#Making http post request
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=body, verify=False)

#Decode response.json() method to a python dictionary for data process utilization
dictData = response.json()

#Json string
json_str = json.dumps(dictData)
print(json_str)
```

print(json_str) output as below

```
{
  "node": [
    {
      "id": "123",
      "ip": "10.101.10.1",
      "model": "md1",
      "type": "basic",
      "name": "aaa"
    },
    {
      "id": "456",
      "ip": "10.101.10.2",
      "model": "sp3",
      "type": "extra",
      "name": "bbb"
    },
    {
      "id": "789",
      "ip": "1.1.1.1",
      "model": "md1",
      "type": "basic",
      "name": "ccc"
    },
    {
      "id": "101",
      "ip": "2.2.2.2",
      "model": "advance",
      "type": "sw1",
      "name": "ddd"
    }
  ],
  "status": "success"
}
```

(2)Extract specific key/value, This is where I'm getting error to get the key/value from the list

```
for i in json_str["node"]:
   if i["type"]=="basic" or i["type"]=="sw1" :
      print(i["name"],i["ip"], i["type"])
```

I'm getting error

```
for i in json_str["node"]:
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

I tried change to json_str[0] but it still doesn't return the key/value that i want.
Please assist further. thanks

**Just use back dictData as it already in dictionary**

```
for i in dictData["node"]
```

Comment: "for i in json_str" should be "for i in dictData", shouldn't it?

Comment: `dictData` already is the json decoded dict. You do not need to use `json.dumps()` on it. Just access `dictData`. You already called that variable `json_str` so aren't you aware that it is a string and not a dict?

Comment: I think I have tested it before...just becoz i got error...I might mix up my code and not aware the line...thanks @trixn for pointing out my mistakes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dumped the json into `str`

Again to work with `dict` first load the `json` and then try

```
json_str = json.dumps(dictData)
json_dict = json.loads(json_str)
print(json_dict)
```

Comment: It working...can the output be save onto text file? using with open("output.txt", "w') ?

Comment: Yes you can save it

Comment: `dictData` already contains the json decoded response. Why should you convert it to a string just to convert it back again? OP should just access `dictData` instead of `json_str`.

Comment: @trixn yes indeed it was. and the convert part into string has been done already in question. I just mention this line again to clear his doubt.

Comment: yup....both of you right....  after long day.... i confuse myself with loads and dumps of  dict and string object...after you mentioned and show me...i know my mistakes... thanks for pointing out... thank you guyz...